# How to print highest power of a polynomial first

Tags: output-formatting, series-expansion

Is there any built-in way to print the highest power of polynomial first and followed by the rest?

```
     In[1]:=  Normal[Series[Log[1-x],{x,0,5}]]
     Out[1]:=-x - x^2/2 - x^3/3 - x^4/4 - x^5/5
```

the expected output is

```
      - x^5/5 - x^4/4 - x^3/3 - x^2/2  - x
```

basically reversing the order.

In addition, I want to save the expression in a text or .m file for further manipulation. TraditionalForm does not serve this purpose.

Comment: This is duplicate. You can try `Normal[Series[Log[1 - x], {x, 0, 5}]] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: There's also [`PolynomialForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/807/4999)

Comment: @Nasser,  this is not the expected output. Of course it reverses the order but in the Traditional form as it should be. What is expected is x^5 + ... This is not what it produces.